# C# webapi POST via console program

Tags: c#, api, post, console, http-post

I have a web api that I can access successfully through a browser :-

https://127.0.0.1:8443/ncrApi

I am trying to create a simple console program in C# using VS2015 to send data and receive a response using http POST.

Here is what I have so far:-

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSample
{

    class ApiSendData
    {
        public string UserID { get; set;}  // username 
        public string Password { get; set;}  // password for the webapi

        public string ApiFunction { get; set; }
        public string DppName { get; set; }
        public string ClearData { get; set; }
        public string DppVersion { get; set; }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The Main function calls an async method named RunAsync 
            // and then blocks until RunAsyncc completes.
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                //specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

                // This code sets the base URI for HTTP requests, 
                // and sets the Accept header to "application/json", 
                // which tells the server to send data in JSON format.
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:8443/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                // HTTP POST
                var datatobeSent = new ApiSendData()
                                    {
                                        UserID = "xxxx",
                                        Password = "yyyy",
                                        ApiFunction ="NcrSecureData",
                                        DppName ="CSampleCustomer",
                                        DppVersion ="Latest",
                                        ClearData ="1234567890",
                                        ResultType = "JSON"
                                    };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("ncrApi", datatobeSent);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Get the URI of the created resource.
                    Uri ncrUrl = response.Headers.Location;

                    // do whatever you need to do here with the returned data //


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my response variable I get the 200 OK http 1.1 message, with content type = application/json and content-length = 174... but no actual data is received...

the variable ncrUrl is also null....

I am wondering if I need additional statements in my console program to receive the data?

Here is what I have been following:-
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: What does this yield? `string payload = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Frame-Options: deny
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Connection: close
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Date: Mon, 25 Jul 2016 21:39:00 GMT
  ETag: "579686f4.174"
  Content-Length: 174
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="results.json"
  Content-Type: application/json
  Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Jul 2016 21:39:00 GMT
}}

Comment: I feel like after this, actual data should be received from the api.

Comment: That looks like JSON so I think it is working but your ncrApi operation is probably not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: But when I access it from the browser... and supply it with the same data, it gives me an output downloadable file. and that file has the right content as well.

Comment: I feel like, I am only getting the first part of the message 200OK... and that there is a second part of the message that contains the output data... but not sure how to access that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading the comments it seems that your api is configured to return a file instead of a string content such as JSON or XML. You can use [HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to read the response stream and save it to a file.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("ncrApi", datatobeSent);

using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("filename.txt")) // change
{
    using (Stream input = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        input.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: The definition for GetResponseStream() is not contained in HttpResponseMessage...

Comment: @Philo yeah sorry about that it's been too long since I last used HttpResponseMessage. See my updated answer. Use `ReadAsStreamAsync()` instead.